# Flatten object within an object in python

Tags: python, lambda

I'm trying to tranform a class I created:

```
class LabeledSourceFeatures:
    label = ''
    features = FeatureSet()

    def __init__(self, label, features):
        self.label = label
        self.features = features

    # added this as part the of the workaround
    def flat_features(self):
        return self.features.__dict__
```

It is easier to create the `FeatureSet` then add it to this class (just saying that to mention that I don't want to just take the members of `FeatureSet` and put them in `LabeledSourceFeatures`), but the end result, I want to put into a pandas dataframe. The problem was, I was getting a data frame with 2 columns, one for the label string and one for the `FeatureSet` object. What I really want is take all the keys and values of my `FeatureSet` and make them their own columns.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
intermediate_data = [(t.__dict__, x.__dict__ for x in t.features) for t in labeledFeatures]

# This fails for syntax error.
```

A workaround is this:

```
intermediate_data = [(t.label, t.flat_features()) for t in labeledFeatures]
final_data = []
for row in intermediate_data:
   new_row = row[1]
   new_row['label'] = row[0]
   final_data.append(new_row)
```

but this looks very inefficient.

Edit:

a `FeatureSet` looks like this:

```
class FeatureSet:
    """
    Adapted from the CSFS presented in De-anonymizing Programmers via Code Stylometry
    by:
        Aylin Caliskan-Islam, Drexel University; Richard Harang, U.S. Army Research Laboratory;
        Andrew Liu, University of Maryland; Arvind Narayanan, Princeton University;
        Clare Voss, U.S. Army Research Laboratory; Fabian Yamaguchi, University of Goettingen;
        Rachel Greenstadt, Drexel University
    """
    # LEXICAL FEATURES
    ln_keyword_length = 0
    ln_unique_keyword_length = 0
    ln_comments_length = 0
    ln_token_length = 0
    avg_line_length = 0

    # LAYOUT FEATURES
    ln_tabs_length = 0
    ln_space_length = 0
    ln_empty_length = 0
    white_space_ratio = 0
    is_brace_on_new_line = False
    do_tabs_lead_lines = False

    comment_text = ''
```

Comment: Can you share a simple way to reproduce your data? What is a `FeatureSet` ? _It is easier to create the FeatureSet then add it to this class_ What do you mean?

Comment: Your class attributes don't appear to play any significant role in your class, other than as documentation.

Comment: No, I supose not... my classes are glorified dicts I suppose. That being said, a class is a bit easier on my IDE.

Comment: No, I mean the class attributes themselves; you don't need, for example, to set a class attribute named `label` to an empty string to indicate that the *instance* attribute of the same name is `str`-valued.

Comment: Ah... Maybe I've been doing typescript / angular too long. I was using those as default values, but I guess the init overwrites those? In either case, I'm not sure fixing that helps what I'm asking though, unless I'm missing what you are saying.